# How to literally translate this: 拌好的萝卜丝儿铺到饼上后?

Tags: translation

...。最关键的功夫是擀面。高手往往把面擀得薄如白纸，拌好的萝卜丝儿铺到饼上后，得再折叠两三次，要求饼熟之后表皮是透明的，能透过表皮看见萝卜丝儿。...

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 19. Please help me to literally translate this clause: 拌好的萝卜丝儿铺到饼上后

Baidu translate: After the mixed radish shreds are spread on the cake

Google translate: After spreading the mixed shredded radish on the cake

Myself I am stuck:

拌： verb, to mix

好：Particle used after verbs to denote the completion or near-completion of an action

拌好：adjective "mixed completed"

萝卜：raphanus

丝儿：is it the erhua (North China) form of 丝? But what exactly means 丝? Silk, classifier?

铺到：to spread, to spread out?

饼： cake

上后：on after? in after? How to make it make sense here?

Comment: 萝卜丝 is a full word for "shredded daikon radish". 萝卜丝儿 is the northern dialect.

Comment: I just want to add that 絲/丝 in this type of cooking context is the equivalent of julienned, if that helps add to existing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 拌 mix(ed)

Verb forms are not marked. The -ed is semantically implied.

> 好 well > grammaticalzed as a marker for verb completion

> 萝卜 daikon, radish

萝卜 refers to the specific subspecies daikon without any context. In this sense, its full name is 白萝卜. Normally using only 萝卜 suffices.

[image: daikon]

萝卜 also refers to the general name of all the subspecifies with appropriate contexts. Besides 白萝卜, the common ones include 胡萝卜 carrots and 红萝卜 red radish.

So if the whole recipe only mentions 萝卜, it's daikon. If it mentions 红萝卜、胡萝卜 or other subspecies in earlier steps, then 萝卜 is sufficient for later references

> 丝 threads

The original meaning of 丝 is the unwoven silk. 丝 is expanded to refer to threads of the shape of silk.

> 儿 erhua

It forms a diminutive. It's used in the Standard Mandarin and northern dialects.

> 铺 spread out

It's used semantically passive.

> 饼 pancake

饼 is a general name of any thin and round flour-made food. The previous sentence mentions 薄饼, and the following sentence mentions 饼熟之后表皮是透明的. So the 饼 here is a specific type of thin pancake, similar to but not the same as 春饼 or 荷叶饼 (the one used in Beijing Duck), since 春饼 is steamed and then wraps foods but here it wrapps foods and then is steamed. I don't know if it has a specific name, but we can call it 薄饼.

[image]

> 到 to

It's originally a verb, grammaticalized as a converb.

> 上 on

到...上 can be viewed as a circumposition, *onto*. It forms a directional phrase, paralleling the locative phrase 在...上.

> 后 after

It forms a temporal phrase, after 拌好的萝卜丝儿铺到饼上.

This clause should be analyzed together with the following one.

> 拌好的萝卜丝儿铺到饼上后，得再折叠两三次。

The subject is omitted. It can be inferred as 铺好萝卜丝儿的饼. 拌好的萝卜丝儿铺到饼上后 is the temporal clause, where 拌好的萝卜丝儿 is the logical object but stands at the subject position in the temporal clause. The verbs in the temporal clause and the predicate are semantically (not formally) passive.

**The well-mixed daikon threads needs to be spread out onto the pancakes. After that they need to be folded two or three times.**

Answer (score 1):

Literally:

拌好的萝卜丝儿铺到饼上后
mix well 的 radish threads 儿 spread to pancake on after

最关键的功夫是擀面。
The most critical skill is rolling the dough.
高手往往把面擀得薄如白纸，
Old hands often roll the dough until it is as thin as paper.
拌好的萝卜丝儿铺到饼上后，
after spreading the mixed shredded radish over the pancake,
得再折叠两三次，
(you) should fold it two or three times,
要求饼熟之后表皮是透明的，
after cooking the surface should be transparent,
能透过表皮看见萝卜丝儿。
(so that) you can see the shredded radish through the pancake.